# How to find whole number answers in systems of square root equations

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

Given the following 4 equations, can you find 4 whole number answers using whole number variable inputs?
$x,y,z$ where $x>y>z$

$Eq 1 = (x^2-2xy+y^2-2xz+z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} $

$Eq 2 = (x^2-2xy+y^2+2xz-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} $

$Eq 3 = (x^2+2xy-y^2+2xz-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$Eq 4 = (x^2+2xy-y^2-2xz+z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} $

for example, $x=1921, y=792, z=272$ yields $551$ in equation 1, but non-whole number answers for remaining 3 equations

Comment: Presumably you don't want the trivial $x=y=z=0$?

Comment: correct!  Should have said naturals not whole numbers.  Plus it needs to satisfy x>y>z

Comment: May I ask where these expressions came from?

Comment: Its a part of a solution to an unsolved riddle

Comment: I've found a bunch of triples that satisfy the first, third, and fourth equations, but oddly none of those (so far) satisfy the second.  The smallest example is $(349, 120, 60)$.

Comment: Amazing! i assume you are running a program to calculate it?  Do you know if there is any way to do this type of problem non-computationally but using math and formulas?  Even graphing?  I don't think you will get an answer in the first couple billion at least, so computational methods hit a wall.  I visualized a simpler version of the problem in 2 dimensions, but i cant figure out how i would go about solving it.

Comment: @BrianTung: There are infinitely many solutions to $(1), (2), (4)$ using an elliptic curve.

Answer (score 0):

Do the substitution $x=c,\,$ $y=x-a,\,$ $z=x-b,\,$ and we get the system,
$$a^2+b^2-c^2 = s_1^2\tag1$$
$$a^2-b^2+c^2 = s_2^2\tag2$$
$$-a^2-b^2+3c^2 = s_3^2\tag3$$
$$-a^2+b^2+c^2 = s_4^2\tag4$$
Solving for $(1)$ as $u_1^2+u_2^2=v_1^2+v_2^2,\,$ and the other three are just *quadratic forms* to be made squares. Then solving simultaneously any two of the remaining three involves an *elliptic curve*, so there are infinitely many solutions to the $3$-out-of-$4$ system. In fact, there is a polynomial solution to $(1), (2),(4)$, a "small" particular example being,

$$x=5405,\; y=4440,\; z=22$$

However, I haven't found a solution for *all* four.